# Android files manipulation

Tags: android

Through the housekeeping stuff my android application has to do is to read and write some files and sometimes to delete others and create new ones. The files in cause have all "sdcard/" as root. Is it safe if I perform all this task using Java style functions ? 
To me it is very handy to do it this way  but I've read that not always the java functions can be applied when it comes to files in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can access `/sdcard` with regular `java.io` classes in Android. But don't hardcode this root; use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` as the root.